# This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-8, xampp

I am trying to run a PHP develop application on my PC with MSSQL and this is the first time I am doing . I have already configured XAMPP on my PC and started Apache

Steps I did:

> Downloaded sqlsrv32.exe

As my Php is

PHP Version 5.6.20

So i copied

> extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and
>   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

to my ext folder 
I have checked php.ini my extension folder is extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

Also on phpinfo() i have

> sqlsrv support enabled
>   Directive   Local Value Master Value
>   sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize    10240   10240
>   sqlsrv.LogSeverity  0   0
>   sqlsrv.LogSubsystems    0   0
>   sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors   On  On

Which meand its already installed, and my database.php file i have following code:

```
$serverName = "KASHIF\\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"RMS Delivery");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

However when I open my application on browser it says :

> Connection could not be established.
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -49 [code] => -49 [2] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 [message] => This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => IM002 [SQLSTATE] => IM002 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified ) )

Then I downloaded  ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server , while installing it says :

> Installation of this product failed because it is not supported on this oeprating system.

I already have SQL SERVER 2012 with Management Studio on my pc.

So please advice what I am leaving or what i am doing wrong .

Thanks

Comment: how you want to connect with your mssql server? using sql driver or using pdo drive? you have configure both of them. and which OS you are using?

Comment: I think XAMPP will require the NON-Thread-Safe DLL's

Comment: Take in mind ODBC Driver provides native connectivity from Windows to Microsoft SQL Server, so you will need it in addition to php sql driver. After installing it, try to download Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP (I'm usign _Windows 10_, _SQL Server_ 2012 and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53` with not issues)

Comment: @Archish i am using WIN8, i have no preference please advice sql driver or using pdo drive which one will be better. Should I remove one and try

Comment: @NachoM. are you talking about sqlsrv32.exe then i have already done that.

Comment: @mark i would recommend to use pod driver. according to me they are best.

Answer (score 0):

You can download pdo driver from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

You will get all driver and help file too which is enough to solve your all query. I use `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` driver for to my localhost.

Comment: i have this `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll ` and i have copied php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll this to ext folder but again error `Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`